# dateFormat in datebox won't effect

Tags: html, jsp, date, datepicker

I'm trying to create a datebox with dateFormat, but it looks like dateFormat won't work.
It gives **day/month/year**, but I want only **month/year**.

this is my jsp:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jquery.mobile.datebox.calbox.min.j‌​s"></script>
    <script src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/i18n/jquery.mobile.datebox.i18n.en_US.utf8.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page">
        <input type="date" name="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode":"calbox","dateFormat":"%m/%Y"}' />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I saw this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11724670/dateformat-option-for-datebox-does-not-work), but still I don't understand why it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like there's an issue in the code that you've provided:

```
http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jquery.mobile.datebox.calbox.min.j‌​s
```

Contains some hidden characters in between "j‌​s". Normally, it would be a hex of 6a73, but in your case, it is 6ae2808ce2808b73 for some reason, so change that link to

```
http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jquery.mobile.datebox.calbox.min.js
```

[Proof](http://www.diffnow.com/?report=ix6f9)

However, to answer your question, try using:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.css" />
    <link type="text/css" href="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.min.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
    <link type="text/css" href="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/simpledialog/latest/jquery.mobile.simpledialog.min.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.core.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.mode.calbox.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.mode.datebox.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.mode.flipbox.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.mode.durationbox.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.mode.slidebox.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/i18n/jquery.mobile.datebox.i18n.en_US.utf8.js"></script>
    <div data-role="page">
        <input type="date" name="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode":"datebox","overrideDateFormat":"%m/%Y","overrideDateFieldOrder": ["m", "y"],"calUsePickers": true, "calNoHeader": true,"calShowDays": false,"calMonthMode": true}' />
    </div>​
```

To force a month/year selection only

[Live Demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/EHRQG/show/) | [Source](http://jsfiddle.net/EHRQG/)

Comment: it's work but (grrr) in chrom it's still won't work. when i open this file with chrome as html file it's working, but when i open it as jsp file from my server(http://...) it's show me also the day(in fire fox it's work both side)

Comment: still the same wont work on chrome, but i found way: i saw in the console--> [blocked] The page at https://localhost/test.jsp ran insecure content from http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.css. and many more like this.. there is a way to avoid this?

Comment: try downloading the files and moving it to your server, then update the links to point to the file.

Comment: The linked resources [don't use https](https://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.css) and so won't work on your site

Comment: great thank you very much for your help!!! so the problem was because i was (*)using https page , (**)miss some scripts and (***)worng char in "http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jquery.mobile.datebox.calbox.min.js" thanks again to "extramaster "